# Use LINQ to Total Columns

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, sum

I'm trying to get LINQ SQL to grab and total this data, I'm having a heck of a time trying to do it too.

[image]

Here is my code, that doesn't error out, but it doesnt total the data.

```
        ' Get Store Record Data
        Dim MyStoreNumbers = (From tnumbers In db.Table_Numbers
        Where tnumbers.Date > FirstOfTheMonth
        Select tnumbers)
```

I'm trying to create a loop that will group the data by DATE and give me the totals so I can graph it.

As you can see, I'd like to set totals for Internet, TV, Phone, ect... Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group and total the numbers one by one, like this:

```
From tnumbers In db.Table_Numbers
Where tnumbers.Date > FirstOfTheMonth
Group by tnumbers.Date
Into TotalPhone = sum(tnumbers.Phone)
Select Date, TotalPhone
```

Here is a link with [explanations of this subject from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918069.aspx).

Edit: added grouping

Comment: I'm trying to create a loop that will group the data by DATE and give me the totals so I can graph it. How can I do that?